# Stacktrace of exceptions in Spring Rest responses

Tags: spring, rest, exception

I have few Rest web services implemented through Spring. The problem is that if any exception is thrown the webservice returns json object with formatted error message that contains stacktrace. Can I have a single point of handling exceptions, and return my custom json objects with messages that wouldn't contain stacktrace?

I see descriptions for spring mvc but im not really using that for building my views etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring provides an out of the box solution to handle all your custom exceptions from a single point. What you need is `@ControllerAdvice` annotation in your exception controller:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public String exception(Exception e) {

        return "error";
    }
}
```

If you want to go deep into Springs `@ExceptionHandler` at individual controller level or `@ControllerAdvice` at global application level [here](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) is a good blog.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's too late, but just pointing out some solutions that may help others!

**case 1**: if you're using `application.properties` file, add following line to your properties file.

```
server.error.include-stacktrace=on_trace_param
```

**case 2**: if you're using `application.yml` file, add following line to your yml file.

```
server:
  error:
    include-stacktrace: on_trace_param
```

**case 3**: **In case, none of them works, try following changes:**

Try to suppress the stack trace by overriding `fillInStackTrace` method in your exception class as below.

```
public class DuplicateFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    @Override
    public synchronized Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

ps1: I referred [this article](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/archives/if_you_use_exceptions_for_path_control_dont_fill_in_the_stac).

Comment: I got an exception when using `on_trace_param` but it seems to work when using just `on_param`. See this page: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorProperties.IncludeStacktrace.html

Answer (score 0):

To handle exceptions thrown from a spring application at a single point, this is the best way to do it. @ControllerAdvice will create an aspect join-point which will intercept all the exceptions with required matching types bound to the corresponding public method.Here, public ResponseEntity handleDataIntegrityViolationException(DataIntegrityViolationException dataIntegrityViolationException,
        WebRequest request) is handling  DataIntegrityViolationException thrown out of the system at one place.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
private HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();

@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

public GlobalControllerExceptionHandler() {
    header.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
}

/**
 * @param dataIntegrityViolationException
 * @param request
 * @return
 */
@ExceptionHandler({ DataIntegrityViolationException.class })
public ResponseEntity<?> handleDataIntegrityViolationException(DataIntegrityViolationException dataIntegrityViolationException,
        WebRequest request) {

    String message = ExceptionUtils.getMessage(dataIntegrityViolationException);
    logger.error("*********BEGIN**************DataIntegrityViolationException******************BEGIN*******************\n");
    logger.error(message, dataIntegrityViolationException.fillInStackTrace());
    logger.error("*********ENDS**************DataIntegrityViolationException*******************ENDS*****************************\n");
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).headers(header).body(dataIntegrityViolationException);
}

}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation with your answers, it will help others in the future. [answer].

Comment: @cosmoonot thanks the suggestion and I have given a brief explanation with in post, please feel free to comment further.